# How to add cloud custodian policies as AWS lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, cloudcustodian

I am new to cloud custodian, where I am exploring the ways to execute custodian policies in lambda.

I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in below doc, but execution is going well but I don't see any lambda function got created in AWS Lambda service.

doc which am referring: https://medium.com/@abhishek.jain.150492/serverless-cloud-custodian-setup-on-aws-lambda-316ec0ed0e83

Let me know if am missing anything here, and share the correct way to achieve this.

Cheers !